# Using a scope with .last is returning an AssociationRelation in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A Client has many Statuses. To get the latest status I'm using the following scope on `Status`.

```
scope :latest, -> { order(:created_at).last }
```

This works as expected in the Rails Console.

```
client = Client.last
client.statuses.latest
=> #<Status id:...
client.statuses.latest.stage
=> 1
```

However, it doesn't work as expected in the view. (This is part of a dynamic form where `f.object` is a `Client` object).

```
<%= f.object.statuses.latest.inspect %>
```

This returns a `Status` object as expected: `#<Status id:...`

But if I now try to access an attribute on the object, `<%= f.object.statuses.latest.stage %>` I get the following error.

```
undefined method `stage' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Which has thrown me, because it should be a `Status` object. Adding to my confusion, if I try a nonexistent attribute, such as `<%= f.object.statuses.latest.foobar %>`, I get the following error.

```
undefined method `foobar' for #<Status:0x007ff615fcdb28>
```

**Update**

I tried setting a `Client` object as an instance variable in the controller to test, and it works as expected. This problem only seems to happen when accessing the `Client` through the form object.

Is this a bug or some kind on limitation? Anyway around it?

**Update 2**

Found a way to fix this.

```
<%= f.object.statuses.latest.stage unless f.object.statuses.latest.blank? %>
```

I don't understand why this works, because latest isn't blank and returns a stage, so if anyone can explain it would be appreciated.

Comment: Weird. Is ``stage`` an attribute or is it a method in ``Status``? Can you provide that?

Comment: `stage` is just an attribute on `Status`, it returns an integer as expected in the Console.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that **All scope methods** will return an **ActiveRecord::Relation**.

I would refactor your model like this to get around this and still get the same functionality.

```
 class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    scope :newest, -> { order(:created_at) }

    def self.latest
       Status.newest.first
    end
 end
```

And you should be able to just call

```
client = Client.last
client.statuses.latest
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Again, this is working in the console, but throws the following exception in the view `undefined method stage for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Check the SQL Query in the Rails log, there is some scoping there that is not returning you anything, if you are getting a nil on **first** then that means the Relation is empty to begin with